# Someone commented this on my Instagram

Tags: translation, meaning, hangul

Someone wrote "캐존잘" on my Instagram. What does this mean? I have tried multiple sources but can't find anything.

Comment: Please include more details: what is the word's context? Which multiple sources have you tried? What didn't you understand about them?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding comments on someone's face, 캐존잘 is *slang praise* for *his (or sometimes, her) extreme handsomeness*. It is just a variant of 개존잘 which consists of 개- and 존잘.

[존잘](https://hinative.com/ko/questions/3717821) is an abbreviation including slang: 존나 잘생겼어, 존나 잘생겼음, ... (Slang 존나 reflects the way 좆 나 is pronounced.) Yet, it can also mean 존나 잘함, 존나 잘해, 존나 잘했음, ... (Then 개존잘 or 캐존잘 is praise for someone's awesome skills, performances, or achievements.) Although the prefix, 개-, should be attached to a *negative* word, some use it to admire a *positive* quality as well.

Comment: Wow. Growing up in the states with Korean parents, apparently I invented my own headcanon all these years. I thought 존나 was a cutesy slang of 정말 ("really") and 개 was an abbreviated slang of 대개 ("very [bigly]").

Comment: @AndrewCheong Right, they’re rather vulgar (“_profane_”) words to use. By the way, you probably mean “되게.” There’s no such words like “대게” or “대개” (“very _bigly_”).