# What does the '개' as in 개웃기네, 개못생겼네 signify?

Tags: meaning

Is it something to be used in certain situations? If so, what are those?

Comment: It is the *non-standard* use of the prefix 개- (which adds the meaning of "the degree being too much"). Related to [this question](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/5471/someone-commented-this-on-my-instagram/5472).

Comment: It is very similar to the word in this [link](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=damn).

Comment: I agree with the definition of urban dictionary Absol referred. "이 커피 개맛있네요" can be translated into "This is a damn fine cup of coffee!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a slang word in Korean used as an intensifier for something. 개`X` means a lot of `X`, a very big `X` or something similar based on context and what X is. It will intensify whatever the word X is trying to convey. In your example:

개웃기네 -> very funny, made you laugh a lot

개못생겼네 -> very ugly

Depending on context it might be considered rude to use this intensifier and is not recommended outside of an informal context

https://www.90daykorean.com/korean-slang/
https://milkcocoahkorean.tumblr.com/post/183187455578/korean-slang-1-%EA%B0%9C

Lots of other examples are available with a quick google search